# Consider a function, . If the function is horizontally translated 3 units to the left and two units down, the new function would be expressed as

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider a function,  . If the function is horizontally translated 3 units to the left and two units down, the new function would be expressed as y=f(x+3)-2 is it ok

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Yes, that is fine. You could say $g(x) = f(x+3)-2$.

Comment: Yes $ y=f(x)$ becomes $ y+k=f(x+h)$ that way if both $(h,k)>0$

Comment: Translating a function to the left/right/up/down does not make much sense, you probably mean translation of a function graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct.

More generally, if we translate $f(x)$ by $h$ units to the right, and $k$ units up, then the new function is $f(x-h)+k$.

Of course, if you tried out specific examples, such as $f(x)=x^2$, you could make a sort of paranoia check. Consider translating $f$ by using the formula above with $h=-3,k=-2$ as in your example. Then we get the new function $g(x) =f(x+3)-2 = (x+3)^2-2$ and the graph appears as so, verifying our answer$^1$:

[image]

$^1$ - At least for this specific example anyhow. It's not a guarantee that our formula is *for sure* correct, but it gives us a bit of security in that at least it works in *this* case.